# EYAML syntax validator?

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I had an issue with an eyaml file used to store password for DB connection and it seems that I missed a "[".

I want to know if there is a command or script to check eyaml syntax

Comment: EYAML is encrypted YAML, so you would decrypt and check its syntax like any other YAML. What specifically are you asking about here?

Comment: Questions asking for tool recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do, if you have python installed somewhere, is install `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) and run the following:

```
python check.py your_eyaml_file
```

with `check.py` being:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
yaml.load(sys.argv[1])
```

This will do a safe load of your YAML file and will throw an error if your file doesn't conform to the YAML specification.

There are also online parsers when you can run such checks, but I would not want to use them with sensitive information (encrypted or not).

Comment: Here is a command line to check the yaml file : 
for i in `find . -name '*.yaml'`; do echo $i; ruby -e "require 'yaml'; YAML.parse(File.open('$i'))";done

the command to decrypt eyaml files is eyaml encrypt -f file

I am trying to combine this to get my eyaml file checked .. any help